# How to restore Production Mysql db to development Mysql db using AWS SDK

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I want to write code c# for some automation which will create snapshot of live(production db) and restore that live mysql db to development environment and before restoring db to development, old instance will be deleted.

We are using Amazon RDS for db.
I have successfully created snapshot from live db but now I am stuck with restore db to development environment.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can automate your stack with CLI commands or if you are using C#, you can use the .NET SDK for making calls. However I suggest you to use CloudFormation, because of it's integrity. ( If you do more than 1 small thing, it handles all your steps as 1 stack, it rolls back/updates as one in case something goes wrong.)

Calling the CloudFormation is simple, you can do it manually, or from the CLI or your C# code with the help of the SDK. ( But in this case, your logic is NOT in your c# code, written on your way, it's in external JSON files. Also by using a separate parameter file, your script is more flexible.)

Also if you using CF, you may want to check one of the generating frameworks like Troposphere.

Comment: Thanks for info. But all I have to use C# .Net AWS SDK.  I can have written some code to create snapshot but now stuck with restoring db part. Can I get some code examples or any tutorials to implement that. I am new to it.

Comment: I'm still suggesting CF: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-dbsnapshotidentifier